# StringBuilder AppendFormat throws IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I have a template define in a string:

```
public static string EntityClassBegginingTemplate =
    @"using System.Collections.Generic;

     //generated by the RuleDesigner
    public abstract class {0}Base : {1}
    {";
```

And then I'm trying it to format a string:

```
builder.AppendFormat(Templates.EntityClassBegginingTemplate, entityName, baseClass);
```

That line throw an exception:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>   System.String.FormatHelper (System.Text.StringBuilder result, IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.Object[] args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/String.cs:1912)
>   System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat (IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.Object[] args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Text/StringBuilder.cs:534)
>   System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat (System.String format, System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Text/StringBuilder.cs:555)

What mistake did I make?

Comment: Unrelated of course, you misspelled `Beginning`.

Comment: if you use @ you have to use escape character for { and } which are {{ and }}. Single { mean that there will be field numer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that the opening curly brace for the class template is being interpreted as a placeholder. You'll need to escape any curly braces that you want treated as literal characters.

```
public static string EntityClassBegginingTemplate =
    @"using System.Collections.Generic;

     //generated by the RuleDesigner
    public abstract class {0}Base : {1}
    {"; <-- this is where the issue likely originated
```

As Ed Plunkett notes, you escape braces by using the double-brace notation , `{{`, [as covered in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx):

> Opening and closing braces are interpreted as starting and ending a
>   format item. Consequently, you must use an escape sequence to display
>   a literal opening brace or closing brace. Specify two opening braces
>   ("{{") in the fixed text to display one opening brace ("{"), or two
>   closing braces ("}}") to display one closing brace ("}"). Braces in a
>   format item are interpreted sequentially in the order they are
>   encountered. Interpreting nested braces is not supported.

Comment: I get System.FormatException, not IndexOutOfRangeException. I wonder if the exception's being thrown somewhere else. At any rate I'd tell her about "{{" escaping.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Given the stack trace, I suspect that may be a difference between the MS implementation and Mono.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point, thanks -- I didn't notice that it was mono.

Comment: I don't think that escape chars are working, as the string is created with the preceding @. This means take it as it is. A Workaround could be to replace the opening curly braket at the end with {2} and add it as a third parameter '{' in the AppendFormat call.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks for the escape hint! :D It works now :)

Comment: @ThomasVoß '@' affects regular C# string literal escaping, which is done in the lexer or something. The curly brace here is being interpreted by the `Format` method at runtime. '{' has no special meaning to the compiler unless it's a '$' interpolation string -- which this isn't.